# Configure internationalization from application.properties in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, spring-boot

I was wondering if I can configure how spring boot handles internationalization using the application.properties file instead of writing it in code.

For example:
To define a `LocaleChangeInterceptor` I have to declare a bean like this:

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>
```

However, a look at the most used properties in the documentation shows only 3 values that can be configured for internationalization:

```
# INTERNATIONALIZATION (MessageSourceAutoConfiguration)
spring.messages.basename=messages
spring.messages.cache-seconds=-1
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
```

So is there a way to achieve this? is there a convention on how to map this to a properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a convention on how to map this to a properties file?

No there isn't. It's only a single bean definition and it's entirely optional, so I would prefer to leave that in Java.

Comment: so it's not possible or not preferable to do so?